# Prerquisites of starting real analysis by N.L Carothers

Tags: education, advice

So I know the elements of analyis up to Riemann intergals nicely. I want to start Carothers' real analysis but some friends are discouraging.

What are the prerequisites of starting real analysis by Carothers'?

Comment: From which books have you studied upto Riemann integral? Don't listen to your friends. Start studying N L Carothers. It's a very good book. But I suggest to keep other books like Rudin, analysis of Apostol, analysis I and II by Tao for reference. Also for some strong set theoretic background you can study Naive Set Theory by Halmos. Also solve problems as mush as possible because solving problems is the best way to learn mathematics and you know that I presume. If you need Problem book suggestions, plz let me know.

Comment: If you have studied elements of analysis upto Riemann integral formally, then you don't need further prerequisites.

Comment: It seems that you're preparing for Chennai Mathematical Institute or ISI Bangalore. I'm an undergraduate student at CMI. You can ask me for any sort of help you need. The exams are on 1st and 2nd August, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShubhrajitBhattacharya .